# Angular 2 DataBinding displaying a list in same <td></td>

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2 so any help is much appreciated.

I am getting data in the form of a `list<user>`. Each user has a list of roles. So in typescript I created this user type:

```
export class User {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    roles: Role[];
}
```

I am parsing the data in above type form. 'users' is an array `users: Array<User>;` in that component.

Displaying the data I want to list out `Role[]` into comma separated values in like `<td>admin, customer, writer</td>`,

but what I am getting instead is:

```
<td>admin</td>
<td>customer</td>
<td>writer</td>
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.firstName +' '+ user.middleName+' '+user.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td *ngFor="let role of Role">{{role.name}}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " (click)="roleOnClick(user)"></button></td>
                </tr>
```

How can I achieve something like `<td> admin, customer, writer</td>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.name}}</td>
```

That line above says to repeat the `<td>` tag for each element of the `Role` array, which is why you're getting the behaviour that you're seeing.

If you just want to get a comma separated list of roles, you may just want to use a simple function call on the role array, for eg:

```
<td> {{ roles.join(', ') }} </td>
```

`join` is a function on the standard JavaScript Array class that allows you to combine the elements of the array simply. The parameter to the function is the text you want to place between each member of the array.

Comment: This is great!! I did not know that. What I did is `<td>{{roles(user)}}</td>` and in my component I did this: `roles(user: User): string {

        let role = user.roles.map(function (elem) {
            return elem.name;
        }).join(",");

        return role;
    }`